# how to install rtl8187 driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, drivers

I tried to install this driver and keeps giving me errors I don't understand!!
here is the log on Aircrack's driver installation

```
In file included from /home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:0:
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:986:24: erreur: field ‘ps_task’ has incomplete type
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_rx_frame_softmac_rtl7’:
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:1512:3: erreur: implicit declaration of function ‘tasklet_schedule’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_softmac_init_rtl7’:
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2229:2: erreur: implicit declaration of function ‘tasklet_init’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_wpa_set_encryption_rtl7’:
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2474:3: erreur: implicit declaration of function ‘request_module’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2503:3: erreur: implicit declaration of function ‘try_module_get’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: Hors de toute fonction :
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2648:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2648:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2648:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2649:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2649:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2649:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2650:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2650:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2650:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2651:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2651:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2651:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2652:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2652:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2652:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2653:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2653:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2653:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2654:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2654:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2654:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2655:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2655:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2655:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2656:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2656:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2656:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2657:1: attention : la définition de données n'a pas de type ni de classe de stockage [enabled by default]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2657:1: attention : type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2657:1: attention : noms de paramètres (sans type) dans la déclaration de fonction [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/younes/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/ieee80211] Erreur 2
make: *** [modules] Erreur 2
```

I hope you help me guys I searched all over the internet and didn't find a working solution :(

Answer (score 1):

You already have this driver pre-installed in the system, this driver should be automatically loaded by the kernel.

Comment: i can't adjust the txpower , i have it 20 by default i want to rise it to 30 even if it allows up to 35 , but iwconfig txpower 30 gives an error , i read about that and found it is a driver problem

Comment: your question is about installing the driver, not configuration files. If you want to customize your driver start a more specific question.

Comment: ok thanks for the hint , i'll post it right away